# is it possible to send ffmpeg images by using pipe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to send images as input to ffmpeg and I want ffmpeg to output video to a stream (webRtc format.)

I found some information that from my understanding showed this is possible. - I believe that ffmpeg could receive image from a pipe, does anyone know how this can be done ?

Comment: Basic syntax is `process-piping-images | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *"I want to **send images as input** to FFmpeg... I believe that FFmpeg could receive image **from a pipe**, does anyone know how this can be done?"*

Yes it's possible to send FFmpeg images by using a pipe. Use the `standardInput` to send frames. The frame data must be uncompressed pixel values (eg: 24bit RGB format) in a byte array that holds enough bytes (`width`x`height`x`3`) to write a full frame.

Normally (in Command or Terminal window) you set input and output as:

ffmpeg `-i inputvid.mp4 outputvid.mp4`.

But for pipes you must **first** specify the incoming input's width/height and frame rate etc. Then aso add incoming input filename as `-i -` (where by using a blank `-` this means FFmpeg watches the `standardInput` connection for incoming raw pixel data.

You must put your frame data into some Bitmap object and send the bitmap values as byte array. Each send will be encoded as a new video frame. Example pseudo-code :

```
public function makeVideoFrame ( frame_BMP:Bitmap ) : void
{
    //# Encodes the byte array of a Bitmap object as FFmpeg video frame
    if ( myProcess.running == true )
    {
        Frame_Bytes = frame_BMP.getBytes(); //# read pixel values to a byte array
        myProcess.standardInput.writeBytes(Frame_Bytes); //# Send data to FFmpeg for new frame encode

        Frame_Bytes.clear(); //# empty byte array for re-use with next frame

    }
}
```

Anytime you update your bitmap with new pixel information, you can write that as a new frame by sending that bitmap as *input parameter* to the above function eg `makeVideoFrame (my_new_frame_BMP);`.

Your pipe's Process must start with these arguments:

```
-y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 800x600 -r 25 -i - ....etc
```

Where...

- `-f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb` means accept *uncompressed* RGB data.
- `-s 800x600` and `-r 25` are example input *width* & *height*, `r` sets *frame rate* meaning FFmpeg must encode this amount of images per one second of **output** video.

The full setup looks like this:

```
-y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 800x600 -r 25 -i - -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -b:v 2500 -an out_vid.h264
```

If you get blocky video output try setting **two** output files...

```
-y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 800x600 -r 25 -i - -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -b:v 2500 -an out_tempData.h264 out_vid.h264
```

This will output a test `h264` video file which you can later put inside an MP4 container.
 The audio track `-i someTrack.mp3` is optional.

```
-i myH264vid.h264 -i someTrack.mp3 outputVid.mp4
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this wonderful answer. I'm facing an issue... I have followed all the instructions you have given, but I am getting a "pipe closed" error before I even write any data. Do you have any tips for me to follow/check? Thank you!

Comment: What programming language says _"pipe closed"_? You have to be running Ffmpeg application as an external `Process` from within your code, that atomatialy makes a pipe (connection) between your code's functions & vars towards the FFmpeg app running from terminal (may give invisible window to user if running as `Process`).

Comment: I used your command line suggestion and I get `x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:4:4`. I think something else is needed if the input `-pix_fmt` is `argb`.

Comment: You can't use colorspace YUV **444** in H264 (Mpeg), it should be **420**. Try adding pixel format after setting baseline, _eg_: `-y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 800x600 -r 25 -i - -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -level...etc`

Comment: @VC.One Alright, I had fixed the error. I had meant to say that **FFMPEG** shows a "pipe closed" error, IIRC. I think I had set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False` and hence it allowed me to redirect the streams.

Comment: Hi how would you do this for a dynamic frame rate? Meaning insert one frame for a duration of say 25 milliseconds, then there best Deanne with a duration of 50 milliseconds etc?

Comment: @SreenikethanI Were you able to send raw data to FFmpeg? Mine always says "invalid date when processing input" and I had to use a named pipe to even be able to send something. Also I'm trying to define the timestamps of each frame as the person above.

Comment: Problem solved. Wrong set of parameters sent to FFmpeg.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767604/pass-individual-frames-as-bgra-byte-array-and-set-the-timestamps-via-pipe-to-ffm/76796090#76796090

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem the fps is static, I think you just need to round the frames as all software do, basically you count the current frame based on elapsed fps time and write the right frame, even if it's already written or sometimes even skipping frames