# Piping to ffmpeg on windows

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, pipe

I'm planning to pipe live image data (bitmaps) to ffmpeg in order to create an AVI file.

Looking at the ffmpeg docs regarding pipes, https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe, it only mentions *UNIX pipes*.

I'm planning using the technique described here: [is it possible to send ffmpeg images by using pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903888/is-it-possible-to-send-ffmpeg-images-by-using-pipe)

Is there a major difference on Windows that causes piping data to ffmpeg not working on Windows?

Comment: The images need not send through a pipe, but the status and command to ffmpeg could be piped.

Comment: @seccpur So where is the image data sent?

Comment: Shared folder. The pictures will loop using -loop command just like a slide show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A follow up to my own question;

Using a named pipe on Windows, works fine with ffmpeg. Currently the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe-y -hide_banner -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -r 80 -s 658x492 -pix_fmt gray -i \\.\pipe\DEV_000F315BE933 -r 80 -c:v rawvideo X:\DEV_000F315BE933_2019T100914.avi
```

can record live video at 80 fps reliably.

Comment: As a follow up, I was reading about limitations after windows 10 v1709. You can only access a named pipe within your app-container. Just wondering if you ever had issues using named pipes from a different shell?