# Pass individual frames as BGRA byte array and set the timestamps via pipe to FFmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, pipe

I have a set of images (as BGRA `byte[]`) with their respective timestamps in milliseconds and I want to pass it to FFmpeg to build an animation.

I'm using FFmpeg v6 right now and in this example I'm expecting a GIF as output, but I'm going to export to multiple formats later.

```
var arguments = "-vsync passthrough  
-f rawvideo 
-pix_fmt bgra 
-video_size {width}x{height} 
-i -  
-loop 0 
-lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=diff[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1:dither=sierra2_4a:diff_mode=rectangle 
-f gif 
-y \"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.gif\"";

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "./ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = arguments.Replace("{width}", width.ToString()).Replace("{height}", height.ToString()),
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

_process.Start();
```

Then on my render loop, I'm trying to send the frames and their timestamps one by one.

```
public void EncodeFrame(IntPtr bufferAddress, int bufferStride, int width, int height, int index, long timestamp, int delay)
{
    var frameSize = height * bufferStride;
    var frameBytes = new byte[frameSize];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bufferAddress, frameBytes, 0, frameSize);

    _process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(frameBytes, 0, frameSize);
    _process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(_delimiter, 0, _delimiter.Length);
    _process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(timestamp), 0, sizeof(long));
}
```

The issue is that I'm getting an IOException (The pipe has been ended), so probably I'm not sending the frames correctly (not sending the delimiter and timestamp doesn't help).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I also gave the same answer in another question, so the text bellow is a copy from that answer.

The way to solve this is by using a named pipe.
Now my only issue is knowing how to set the timestamp (or duration of each frame).

---

Here's a proper way of creating a named pipe and setting as input to a FFmpeg command.

Let's first declare some variables:

```
private Process _process;
private NamedPipeServerStream _pipeServer;
private StreamWriter _pipeStreamWriter;
private const string _pipeName = @"pipe_to_ffmpeg";
private readonly string _pipeStructured = @"\\.\pipe\" + _pipeName;
```

Then let's create a process and pass the necessary parameters:

```
public void Start(string ffmpegPath, int width, int height)
{
    //Example argument, used to export GIFs
    var arguments = "-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -video_size {width}x{height} " +
        $"-i {_pipeStructured} " +
        "-loop 0 " +
        "-lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=diff[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1:dither=sierra2_4a:diff_mode=rectangle " +
        "-f gif -fps_mode passthrough " +
        "-y \"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ffmpeg.gif\"";

    _process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = ffmpegPath,
            Arguments = arguments.Replace("{width}", width.ToString()).Replace("{height}", height.ToString()),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    _pipeStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(_pipeServer);

    var pipeServerThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Needs to be in a separate thread or you could use other async methods.
        _pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        _pipeStreamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    });
    pipeServerThread.Start();

    _process.Start();
}
```

Then on your render iterator, you can pass data via the `StreamWriter`:

```
public void Encode(byte[] buffer, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    while (!_pipeServer.IsConnected) //TODO: Limit wait period.
        Thread.Sleep(100);

    //Here you may want to spend some time understanding how to properly pass the data to FFmpeg.
    _pipeStreamWriter.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Don't forget to clean and dispose everything later:

```
public void Finish()
{
    _pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
    _pipeStreamWriter.Dispose();
    _pipeServer.Dispose();

    _process.WaitForExit();
}
```